# Angular routing with default as '' route and '**' for 404 not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular8

In my `app-routing.module` file, I have some child routes, an empty route for default login page and one '**' route for `404` pages.

Giving the code below

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('<module path>').then(mod => mod.<module name>)
  },
  {
    path: 'customer',
    loadChildren: () => import('<module path>').then(mod => mod.<module name>)
  },
  {
    path: 'user',
    loadChildren: () => import('<module path>').then(mod => mod.<module name>)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('<module path>').then(mod => mod.<module name>)
  },
  {
    path: '404',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent,
    canActivate: null
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/404',
    canActivate: null
  }

];
```

By using this code, **I am not able to go to the 404 page as it will always redirect to the route('') page.** I then changed the order of the route and add the empty('') route at the last and then the `404` worked but **event the root empty('') URL (http://localhost:4200) redirects to `404` URL**. Is there any way that I can keep the empty URL for login and make the `404` work?

Comment: have you try with blank route path first.

Comment: @Arun add this `pathMatch: 'full'`

Comment: try redirect wihtout `/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid the '' path to redirect at all times:

```
{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('<module path>').then(mod => mod.<module name>)
    pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

Also as a suggestion I would leave the '**' path for all unexpected routes to simplify your code:

```
{
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
}
```

You can erase the "canActivate" if you're not using guards :)